# How to show SKShapeNode inside another SKShapeNode and separate fields

Tags: skshapenode, snapkit, skfieldnode

I want to show circles inside another circles.
I have SKScene with radialGravityField. Big circles (SKShapeNode) have physicsBody.

```
self.physicsBody = {
          let path = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius).path!
          let body = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
          return body
        }()
```

(radius passed in init)

Inside big circles i want to create another radialGravityField, which will work only for small inner circles (SKShapeNode with physicsBody).
But when I add add child node to big circle it sticks to border of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qcqm.png)

Is any way to add child SKShapeNode inside another SKShapeNode? And resize parent circle depending on child circles size

What I want:
radial gravity field inside big circles, which will work only for inner small circles.
Big circle changes size when child node appears inside id.
Like on this screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8fjN.png)

UPDATE:
showing small circles inside big circles I done using categoryBitMask, collisionBitMask
and separate fields using fieldBitMask
everything works as expected.